# Ionic Sqlite SELECT IN statement doesn't return correct results

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have ionic mobile application where I use Sqlite plugin. I try to run following query:

```
this.db.executeSql('SELECT * FROM foo_table WHERE id IN (?)', [[1, 3]])
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data.rows.item(0));
        console.log(data.rows.item(1));
        // Do something here
    });
```

I have on purpose left showing the database initialization code because it is unnecessary because it works properly with other methods in the same file. In database I have two entities in **table_foo** which contain some specific data and each entity have id.

When I run above statement it doesn't return those two entities which ids are 1 and 3. Instead it return `undefined`. I run exact same statement in sqlite console that is `SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE id IN (1,3);` and this works. It shows correctly the two entities. My question is why Sqlite `SELECT IN` query above doesn't work properly and how I should properly add many values in params (where is located array of values 1 and 3)? Am I using it (SELECT IN query) wrong?

When I run above query with params as:

- `[1]` -> works
- `[[1]]` -> works
- `[[1, 3]]` -> doesn't work
- `[1, 3]` -> error which is quiet obvious

Comment: You need something like `SELECT ... id IN (?,?)` and bind values of `[1,3]`.

Comment: That's bad solution, because I can have an array which contains 7 elements, or sometimes it can contain 20 elements. By taking this into account I can't do your suggestion.

Comment: It's the only solution. If you don't know how many values to bind until runtime, you can build a query string with the appropriate number of question marks then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two workarounds for this:

1. Concatenating array values as strings (not good solution):

```
const ids = [1, 3];
this.db.executeSql('SELECT * FROM foo_table WHERE id IN (' + ids.toString()')', [])
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data.rows.item(0));
        console.log(data.rows.item(1));
        // Do something here
    });
```

2. Using sql `SELECT` in `SELECT IN` query (**good solution if you can fetch those values from database table**):

```
this.db.executeSql('SELECT * FROM foo_table_a WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM foo_table_b)', [])
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data.rows.item(0));
        console.log(data.rows.item(1));
        // Do something here
    });
```